# how do I fix this error on debian 10, I'm not sure what the issue is

Tags: debian, debian-buster, snapcraft

I tried to install snapcraft using the instruction from here https://snapcraft.io/docs/installing-snap-on-debian 
And later tried to install shotcut using "sudo snap install shotcut --classic" 
However I get this error 
 "error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount:
       /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-501228691: mount failed: Operation not permitted." 
how do I fix this, I'm using debian 10

Comment: It might be useful if you explained what you have tried that has worked. For example, have you tested that `snapd` is installed correctly? There are instructions for testing this at the link you provided. It seems to me that you may be attempting to install `shotcut` without having first ensured that `snapd` is functioning, since the error you posted suggests an issue with `snapd` and not `shotcut`.

Comment: No I didn't  test it, I just thought It'd be working

Answer (score 1):

The issue might be related to trying to run snap inside a container (a VPS, or a docker container) that does not have the correct configuration to run snap.

To run snap nicely inside a container... Look for the following keywords:

`openvz`
`/dev/fuse`
`CAP=SYS_ADMIN`
`--privileged`
`loopback`
'modprobe fuse'

my advice is to not use `snap` and to use `apt-get` instead.

more on that here:
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/system-does-not-fully-support-snapd-cannot-mount-squashfs-image-using-squashfs/132689