# Snapd error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using .... Operation not permitted. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, certbot, squashfs, snap

Im trying to install certbot and snapd core etc and it gives me this error:

error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using
"squashfs": mount: /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-718641914: mount failed:
Operation not permitted.

I have searched for so long and haven't found anything. If someone has a solution for this, please tell me.

Comment: Could you provide the precise command line that gave the error please? Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62108224/how-do-i-fix-this-error-on-debian-10-im-not-sure-what-the-issue-is/74263113#74263113